# How do I check if the response contains an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to enable the icon if an array is present in the response. How do I check if an array is present in the response?

Code snippet I have tried:

```
 export function disableActions(name, data) {
    case i18next.t('abcd'):
        return (
            data.contains('asdf')) 
        );
```

I have to enable the abcd icon, only if data contains asdf array, if not disable the icon.

I have tried `data.contains('asdf')` and `data.includes('asdf')`.

Comment: what is `case` here ? a switch case ?

Comment: yes a switch case

Comment: Are you switching name?. Check what is returned from i18Next

Comment: case i18next.t('abcd'):
   return (
    (data.status !== NSConst.DEPLOYED &&
                                  data.status !== NSConst.RUNNING &&
     data.contains('asdf')) 
   );


the other two condition is working fine, so there is no issue with switch case .

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method to check if a variable is an Array.

```
if(Array.isArray(data.asdf)) {

}
```

Comment: initially i have to check whether the data contains an element (asdf)or not, i dont want to iterate an array

just a presence of an element enable it or disable it kind of...


i tried data.contains('asdf')